# Add an attribute using xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

I want to add an attribute to the tag, using **xmllint**.
Can I do this is through xmllint?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xmllint in not made to edit XML, so I think the answer is “no, you can't”.

To edit XML, you can use XMLStarlet, the syntax to add an attribute into existing XML document is:

`xmlstarlet ed -L -i xpath -t attr -n name -v value  file`

Comment: It can be done with `xmllint` as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060915/2834978)