# Bash Script to append classes to html file

Tags: html, bash, shell

I have a html file that has multiple nested tables:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
               <tr>
                 <td>
                      <table>
                       ...
                       </table>
                 </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I would like to add classes to each of the tables as such:

```
      <table class="table1">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table2">
               <tr>
                 <td>
                      <table class="table3">
                       ...
                       </table>
                 </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
```

Based on extensive searches, I cobbled the following bash script, but it's not working at all:

```
#!/bin/bash
strng="<table"
index=1
for entry in `grep -n $strng $1`
do
line=`echo $entry | awk -F":" '{print$1}'`
sed -e "$line s/$strng/$strng class=\"table$index\"/" -i $1
index=$(($index + 1))
done
```

Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: `awk` is the more suitable tool for this task. Using `bash` loop for text processing is the bad practice. Read here: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/109397)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a general solution, you should use an html-specific tool.  If you know that your html is limited to the format that you show, then try:

```
awk '/<\/table>/{i--} /<table>/{sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">")} 1' file.html
```

#### Example

```
$ awk '/<\/table>/{i--} /<table>/{sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">")} 1' file.html
    <table class="table1">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table2">
               <tr>
                 <td>
                      <table class="table3">
                       ...
                       </table>
                 </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

#### How it works

1. `/<\/table>/{i--}`

   For any line that contains `</table>`, we decrement variable `i`.
2. `/<table>/{sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">")}`

   For any line that contains `<table>`, we increment variable `i` and substitute in `<table>` with the class value.
3. `1`

   This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Changing the file in-place

If you want to change the file in-place and you have GNU awk (gawk), then use:

```
awk -i inplace '/<\/table>/{i--} /<table>/{sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">")} 1' file.html
```

For other awk:

```
awk '/<\/table>/{i--} /<table>/{sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">")} 1' file.html >tmp && mv tmp file.html
```

#### As a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: script.sh infile outfile
awk '/<\/table>/{i--} /<table>/{sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">")} 1' "$1" >"$2"
```

Note that the file names, `$1` and `$2`, are inside double-quotes.  This prevents surprises in case the names contain whitespace or other shell-active characters.

As a matter of style, not substance, some people prefer spreading out awk code over multiple lines.  This can make it easier to understand the code or to modify the code when one wants to add new features.  Thus, if one likes, the above script can also be written as:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: script.sh infile outfile
awk '
    /<\/table>/{ i-- }

    /<table>/{ sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">") }

    1
    ' "$1" >"$2"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked pefectly. I  used your suggestion thus: `#! /bin/bash
awk '/<\/table>/{i--} /<table>/{sub(/<table>/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\">")} 1' $1 > $2
exit`

Comment: By the way, if you want to know why I'm trying this, is because Gnucash has extremely limited formatting capabilities when printing reports. However, It allows one to export to html where I can apply css styles. But this is a story for another time.

Comment: @AlanW Very good!  Glad it worked.  I added your script to the answer with some minor changes.  I haven't used Gnucash but that sounds interesting.

Comment: I should have provided more details. Awk works for the table tag as I presented, which is not a real-world example. my code actually had this: `<table width='600.00' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>` so I modified the awk line: `awk '/<\/table>/{i--} /<table/{sub(/<table/, "<table class=\"table"++i"\"")} 1'`

Comment: One more thing @John1024, somehow the code failed to enumerate past 'class=table2' so I removed `'/<\/table>/{i--}`

Comment: @AlanW  It enumerated past 2 in the sample html (as shown in my answer).  But, in the code, `i` is counting _nesting depth_.  If you want to enumerate tables, not track their depth, then yes, removing `/<\/table>/{i--}` would be the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a quick solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp_file="$( mktemp )"
sed 's/\(<table\)/\1 class="$_field_$"/g' "$1" > "$temp_file"
index=0
while grep -e '[$]_field_[$]' "$temp_file" >/dev/null
 do
    sed -i "s/[$]_field_[$]/$index/" "$temp_file"
    ((++index))
 done
cp "$temp_file" "$1"
rm -f "$temp_file"
```

But it has to be mentioned that manipulation of XML attributes should not be done using tools like `sed` or `awk`. Use a purpose-built tool as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404497/4049863).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting xmlstarlet from the other post. I'll try that one next. Of course, it is always best to use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 1):

To address why your script is not working: `for X in Y` splits on whitespace, not only newlines like you're expecting.

Set `$IFS` to newline and it should work as intended.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
strng="<table"
index=1
for entry in `grep -n $strng $1`
do
  line=`echo $entry | awk -F":" '{print$1}'`
  sed -e "$line s/$strng/$strng class=\"table$index\"/" -i $1
  index=$(($index + 1))
done
```

Otherwise your grep command is returning:

```
1:    <table> 
4:            <table>
7:                      <table>
```

and processing in 6 iterations:

```
1:
<table>
4:
<table>
7:
<table>
```

You can see this by adding `set -x` to the top of your script to get a trace of the commands.

Comment: Sorry, but adding IFS wiped the file and substituted all text with 419 lines of: `ellpadding="0"> s/<table class="table1"/<table class="table31"/  ...  ellpadding="0"> s/<table class="table419"/<table class="table31"/`

Comment: Then there must be some other condition not covered in the test you posted. I get the desired output exactly. Either way, the `awk` solution posted by @john1024 is certainly the better approach.

Comment: Thank  you, @mjb2kmn, perhaps it's an environment issue dealing with gnu, posix, or some other cryptic OS variable. I'm using Linux Mint 17.