# XMLStart insert a line in XML file

Tags: linux, xml, shell

This is how my XML looks like.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="xxxxxxxx" android:versionName="xxxxx" package="xxxxxx" xmlns:android="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

I need to add the below line after the <application

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

So, the output should look like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="xxxxxxxx" android:versionName="xxxxx" package="xxxxxx" xmlns:android="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

I've tried sed command but still no luck. everybody suggests to use XMLSTART.

```
sed -i '/<application/a android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"' AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might look like:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -i '/manifest/application' -t attr -n android:networkSecurityConfig -v '@xml/network_security_config' \
  -i '/manifest/application' -t attr -n android:requestLegacyExternalStorage -v true \
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If `xmlstarlet` is not available or not preferred, adding an attribute to an element can be done with `xmllint` with a bit of work

```
# get uses-feature element
uf="$(xmllint --xpath '/manifest/uses-feature' tmp.xml)"

# get application attributes
attrs="$(xmllint --xpath '/manifest/application/@*' tmp.xml | tr '\n' ' ')"

# append desired attributes
attrs+=' android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"'

# build manifest inner xml
inner="<application $attrs></application>$uf"
# restore manifest inner xml (with @CharlesDuffy kind suggestion)
printf '%s\n' setrootns 'cd /manifest' "set $inner" save bye  | xmllint --shell tmp.xml
```

**Note:** output from `xmllint --xpath '/manifest/application/@*' tmp.xml` contains new lines that must be removed before using it on `set` command

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:supportsRtl="true"
```

For other cases where content contains several nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="xxxxxxxx" android:versionName="xxxxx" package="xxxxxx">
  <a>text1</a>

  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
  
  <b>
      <c>text2</c>
  </b>
</manifest>
```

the following XPath should be used to get everything but the element to be changed

```
xmllint --xpath '/manifest/*[not(name()="application")]' tmp.xml
```

Result

```
<a>text1</a>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<b>
      <c>text2</c>
  </b>
```

Comment: Interesting. Think about `printf '%s\n' setrootns 'cd /manifest' "set $inner" save bye` to avoid needing `echo -e`.

Comment: BTW, what's the point of the command substitution running echo in the second-to-last line? Why not just `inner="<application $attrs></application>$uf"`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy echo was there because it was followed by `tr -d '\n'` but then I removed new lines from attrs and fixed the issue. The point is that `xmllint` expects `\n` at the end of the command. That might be a problem if new node must contain new lines, may be using `\\n` could help to preserve them.

Comment: The shell deletes any trailing newline present in command substitution results; `foo='bar'` and `foo=$(echo bar)` result in 100% identical values stored in `foo`, neither of which is identical to `foo=$'bar\n'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the kind suggestions! Changed answer accordingly.